# How to change browser's Memory Cache to Disk Cache

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, web, caching

When I load a website created with ASP.NET Core in the browser, css files are saved in Disk Cache and js files are saved in Memory Cache. (I checked it in the network tab in developer mode.)

Since the js file is stored in Memory Cache, if I turn off the browser and turn it back on to access the site, the js file will be downloaded again.

But, because the css file is stored in Disk Cache, if I turn off the browser and then turn it back on to access the site, the css file will not be downloaded again.

How do I save js files to Disk Cache?

Comment: A) What browser? B) What differences, if any, in the headers for JS vs. CSS?

Comment: Tried it in Edge and Chrome. The content-type is different. And, the css cache-control is set to "max-age=31536000,immutable".

Comment: A page's memory cache is only for the session.  (JS files are still cached to disk...)  You'll see this in dev-tools in Chrome, for instance, if you look at the 'Network' tab.  The size will show "(cache)" when loading from disk cache.